# Why does text interpolation in Angular not work on non-default attributes?

Tags: html, angular, attributes

Heyo, I'm trying to understand how and when text interpolation works in Angular. It seems to remove certain combinations. Let me give you a few examples:

```
<img src="{{'test'}}">                  //works
<span src="{{'test'}}"></span>          //gets removed
<span data-test="test"></span>          //works, duh
<span data-test="{{'test'}}"></span>    //gets removed
<span [attr.data-test]="'test'"></span> //works
```

Just to be clear, the DOM will contain all the img and span elements but they won't always have the attributes I defined. Angular just throws some away.

My theory is the following: text interpolation for HTML attributes only works for attributes inserted according to HTML spec. Since `<img>` supports the `src` attribute, I can use text interpolation there. `<span>` doesn't, so it gets removed there. But there's nothing related to this in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation) afaik. So I can't really be sure. How does it work and when does it not?

Edit: the background to my question is that I want to use `{{}}` as often as possible over attribute binding cause I think it looks nicer. Though I neither have an idea which one performs better nor why text interpolation doesn't always work.

Answer (score 0):

Angular and binding check if the property exists in the element, if it is null or undefined is removed.

**Let see each case:**

`<img src="{{'test'}}">` WORKS because the attribute **src** is part of the **img** element.

`<span src="{{'test'}}"></span>` REMOVED, the attribute **src** is not part of **span** and resolves to **null** or **undefined**, and angular removes the attribute.

`<span data-test="test"></span>` WORKS, because the data-test is a standard way to add property and not use binding.

`<span data-test="{{'test'}}"></span>` REMOVED because the binding check the data property is not part of span, angular check the data-test attribute is not valid and is removed.

`<span [attr.data-test]="'test'"></span>` WORKS it is the way as angular register the custom attribute `attr-data-test` and keep and assign the value.

**RECAP**
For binding attributes, use attribute binding to bind properties and custom attributes.

```html
<img [src]="path"/>
```

For custom attributes uses:

```html
<img [attr.data-nice]="hello"/>
```

Feel free to read more https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding

Comment: My question already contained attribute binding as a working example. I know. My question is why the other one doesn't work. And why it sometimes does.